# How do I create a unique combination constraint/index in MySQL? (NOT permutation)

Tags: mysql, indexing, constraints, combinations

How do I create a unique combination constraint/index in MySQL? I do not mean a permutation. The order does not matter.

For example: I have two users that I want to match up together with a linking table. The table has nothing more than two columns which are both foreign keys corresponding to the primary key on the users table.

How do I create an index that will ensure that the pair remain unique in either order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your application enforce that col1 < col2 - this provides a consistent order and ensures only a single linking row will ever be generated. This does not mesh well with your preconditions ("in either order"), but it sounds like it should work for your situation. I ran into a similar problem before, before project requirements changed to asymmetric user relationships (a la Twitter).

Comment: Simple. Good solution even if it isn't MySQL index enforced...simple enough to implement.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand your question. you want to add Unique Constraint combining two columns.
so try

```
ALTER TABLE `tableName` ADD UNIQUE (
`first_column` ,
`second_column`
);
```

Comment: But doesn't this only ensure that if first_column = 1 and second_column = 4 that I can't insert a record (1,4) but not that I can't insert a column (4,1)?

Comment: you can insert `(4,1)` and `(1,4)` because both are unique combination

Comment: What I'm wanting is to consider that (1,4) == (4,1)